Localizar tablas que no se utilizan de una BD
Estoy trabajando en una base de datos de sql server y me solicitan enlistar las tablas que se están utilizando e identificar las que no para depurarla como puedo identificar las tablas de esa BD que no se están utilizando?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Tu pregunta es algo ambigua. Te recomiendo usar SQL Server Profiler para crear una nueva traza y seleccionar eventos relacionados con consultas (por ejemplo, SQL:BatchCompleted y RPC:Completed). Si puedes proporcionar más contexto o detalles específicos, podremos ayudarte mejor.

¿Qué significa "las tablas que no se estan utilizando"? ¿Las que tienen 0 registros? ¿Las que no se utilizan desde tu software? (sólo se podrá saber revisando el código del software)
